# How to remove repeating non-adjacent string

Tags: python, regex

Given lines that look like the following:
`Blah \cite[9.1173]{Joyce:1986aa}\autocite[42]{Kenner:1970ab}\autocite[108]{Hall:1960aa} bbb.\n`
I’d like to remove the second (and any subsequent) occurrence of `\autocite`, resulting in the following:
`Blah \autocite[9.1173]{Joyce:1986aa}[42]{Kenner:1970ab}[108]{Hall:1960aa} bbb.\n`

I’m struggling to express this in regex form (I’m using the python 2.7 RE module), however, as I’m not sure how to formulate 
“remove only the second and subsequent occurrences of `\autocite` when followed by `[…]{…}`, until a space or period is encountered”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular expressions are not a panacea.

```
l = s.split('\\autocite')
print '%s\\autocite%s' % (l[0], ''.join(l[1:]))
```

Comment: You’re absolutely right. Couldn’t see the wood for the trees.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutly want regexes you can use `(?<=\\autocite)(.*?)\\autocite(.*)` and replace with `\1\2`.

But @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams answer is way better an efficient.